# Existe algum problema de race condition no meu código?

Tags: vb.net, paralelismo, sincronização, volatile

Existe algum problema de *race condition* no código abaixo?

```vb
Private Shared Sub TestRandomNumberGeneration(ByVal random As Random)
    Dim failed As Boolean = False
    Parallel.For(0, 100000, Sub(i, state)
        Dim [next] As Integer = random.Next()
        If [next] = 0 Then
            Volatile.Write(failed, True)
            state.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub)
    Assert.IsFalse(failed)
End Sub
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela formatação :D

Comment: De nada! Agora em cores :)

Comment: Ficooooou massa :D :D :D :D

Comment: @HorácioJ.C.Filho você pode aprender o essencial de edição aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help , para as próximas perguntas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende. Se o método `Stop` do objeto `state` só pode ser chamado uma vez (o que não está claro na questão), então sim, há uma possibilidade, ainda que pequena, de mais de um thread chamar esse método. E é possível, mesmo sem o paralelismo, que o `Assert.IsFalse(failed)` falhe - zero é um resultado possível pra função `random.Next()` (assumindo que `random` é do tipo `System.Random`).

Se o método `Stop` pode ser chamado mais de uma vez, e se for aceitável que o `Assert.IsFalse` falhe, então não há uma condição de corrida no código. Isso depende da hipótese que você tem sobre o seu código.